# passing sftp commands to sftp connection in a file

Tags: shell-script, scripting, sftp

How can I pass a script to an sftp connection?
e.g.

I make the sftp connection thus:

```
#sftpscript.sh
serverIP="1.2.3.4"  
sftp $serverIP
```

So far so good.
Now I have a script the looks like this:

```
#sftpscript.sftp
lcd /path/to/newdir
cd /path/to/newdir
get filename.log.*
rm filename.log.*
```

I tried:

```
sftp $serverIP:/path/to/sftpscript.sftp
```

but this just says it can't find `sftpscript.sftp` Is this possible? or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to man page (e.g. `sftp(1)` ), syntax is

```
 sftp -b /path/to/sftpscript.sftp  $serverIP
```

however, I am not sure globbing option will work. (e.g. `file.*` )

Comment: SFTP has its own globbing expansion ways that considers the context (e.g. `put blah* blah/` puts all local files starting with `blah` into the remote `blah/` dir), and I think it should work just like we use the interactive SFTP.

Comment: that's worked perfectly, cheers for that.